# If $R$ is a unital commutative ring, then the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is an $R$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Assume we have a unital commutative ring $R$ and a polynomial ring $R[x]$. How is the ring-homomorphism $$f:R \to R[x]$$ explicitly defined, such that $$f(R) \subset Z(R[x])?$$ That is, how can we define $f$ so that $$(R[x],f)$$ becomes an $R$-algebra.

I am trying to gain intuition for this.

Edit: I would be interested to see how this is done in the case when we look at $(R[x_1,\ldots,x_n],f)$ as well.

Comment: If $R$ is commutative, $R[x]$ is commutative, so $Z(R[x])=R[x]$... Are you asking how to define the map $R \rightarrow R[x]$?

Comment: The usual map is defined by $r \in R$ maps to $r\in R[x]$, the polynomial with only a degree 0 term. Then, $r\cdot g(x) = r\cdot \sum_i r_ix^i = \sum_i r(r_ix^i) = \sum_i (r_ix^i)r = (\sum_i r_ix^i)r = g(x)\cdot r$, so indeed $f(R)$ is in the center of $R[x]$. In fact, as @JonasLinssen notes, $R[x]$ is commutative, so $Z(R[x])=R[x]$.

Comment: It may feel less confusing to use the classic definition of an algebra over $R$. It is a tuple $(A, +, \times, \circ, R)$ s.t. $(A,+,\circ)$ is a ring, $(A, +, \times, R)$ is a module over $R$ and $r(ab)=a(rb)$ for all $r\in R, a,b \in A$). It's a good exercise to check the equivalence of these deifinitions. And in terms of the first definition it's quite easy to define $R$-algebra structure on $R[t_i]$ for any number of free variables (exactly $r\times P := r\circ P$). And then you may restore the homomorphism using the exercise above